# Lost aspx.cs page after Power failure in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a web application using visual studio 2010, After power failure, My aspx.cs page opens in a notepad instead of visual studio and i can't able see any code in that file. Is there any way to recover this file?

Comment: What do you mean by "My page opens in a notepad"?

Comment: My aspx.cs page opens in notepad

Comment: it's problem with computer, you can try System Restore